# update with multiple inner joins in db2

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following query

```
UPDATE mainList
INNER JOIN custToList D
    ON l.custToList_id = d.custToList_id
INNER JOIN dealert dt
    ON d.dealert_id = dt.dealert_id
INNER JOIN markList m
    on m.markList_id = d.markList_id
SET EXPIRATION_TIMESTAMP = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
where dt.custNum = 2;
```

BUt it's telling me the first 'inner' is not valid? Can you not do inner joins on updates in db2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think DB2 supports `JOIN` in `UPDATE`.  In your case, this is easily fixed by moving the filtering to the `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE mainList l
    SET EXPIRATION_TIMESTAMP = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM custToList D INNER JOIN
                   dealert dt
                   ON d.dealert_id = dt.dealert_id INNER JOIN
                   markList m
                   ON m.markList_id = d.markList_id
              WHERE l.custToList_id = d.custToList_id AND dt.custNum = 2
             );
```